# PostInstallScript with second generation package

Tags: package, salesforcedx

Is it possible to specify a PostInstallScript, or UninstallScript, using the second generation packaging API?

I haven't yet found any reference to it in the DX documentation, the [SFDX project file documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm) or the [cli reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package2.htm), but it would seem to be a rather big omission if it's not there, which makes me think it's something I've missed.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything; 2GP is meant to organize code into units, not necessarily replace the managed package concept. But I'd love to be wrong about this.

Comment: @sfdxfox Ah, I thought I read that you could just package using 2GP and do away with the packaging org entirely, which would be great - but I've probably got the wrong end of the stick!

Comment: This is a very valid question for Managed 2GP. Since that's still in Beta, it might very well be a feature gap.

Comment: 3 years on and this question is still relevant. I have created an idea, perhaps you can upvote if you find it interesting? https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lPKTQA2

Answer (score 5):

You can define the postInstallScript and UninstallScript within the file `sfdx-project.json` or when you use `sfdx force:package:version:create`

Source:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_customize_installs.htm

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_sf_cli_nc.htm