# Adding a post-install script to a second generation managed package

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, postinstall, second-generation-packaging

I'm creating a second gen managed package using sfdx and I'm not sure how to add a post-install script. Most information I've come across involves updating the package from within an org. Is this option available to me when creating 2GP packages?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this stackEchange item: [PostInstallScript with second generation package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208480/postinstallscript-with-second-generation-package)

> You can define the postInstallScript and UninstallScript within the file sfdx-project.json or when you use sfdx force:package:version:create

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_customize_installs.htm

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_sf_cli_nc.htm